# Error al instalar/usar el módulo mysql.connect en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysqlconnector

Tengo la siguiente situación y no sé dónde está el error.

Si ejecuto Python3 desde la terminal y hago `import mysql.connector`, puedo armar la conexión, ejecutar una consulta, etcétera.

Pero si en lugar de eso armo un script en un archivo, ejemplo "consulta.py" y lo ejecuto con `python3 consulta.py`, me da un error indicando que el módulo no está instalado.

¿Qué me falta hacer?

```
python3 mysql.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "/home/chelo/Temporal/mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
```

Comment: Has llamado a tu script `mysql`, igual que el paquete que quieres importar. O tienes un fichero llamado `mysql.py` en la misma carpeta. Cambiale el nombre.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave, el archivo mysql.py sólo contenia el `import`

Comment: yo tengo ese problema, y mi archivo se llama prueba.py, alguna idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto sucede porque el script que se intenta ejecutar (mysql.py) se llama igual al paquete 'mysql'. Si renombras el archivo (por ejemplo a consulta.py) se puede ejecutar normalmente con

```
python3 consulta.py
```